# Cannot read property 'onPageChanged' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

sample extension background.js code

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
      conditions: [
        // When a page contains a <video> tag...
        new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
          pageUrl: { hostEquals: 'www.youtube.com'}
        })
      ],
      // ... show the page action.
      actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
    }]);
  });
```

});

and I got Cannot read property 'onPageChanged' of undefined in console. No problem running the code, why is that happening?

Answer (score 32):

Check that you have added the **declarativeContent** permission to your manifest.json file.
This will give your extension access to the [chrome.declarativeContent](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent) API and should resolve your problem.

Comment: If you're still seeing the error after completing this step, try clicking "Clear All" on the extension Errors page. The error messages persist even after you've corrected them. Try clearing, then reloading the extension. If you don't see the error anymore, you're good.

Comment: Thank you @J.D.Mallen! I was beginning to thing I was going crazy!

Comment: how to see all permission available?

Comment: Holy cow, nobody else online--SO answers nor blog posts--ever seemed to explicitly spell out that you need to declare permissions for this. The permissions needed are listed at the top of the offiical docs ( https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeContent/#type-PageStateMatcher ), tucked away in a totally ignorable tiny little header space, but nowhere did I ever read anything akin to "Declare `declarativeContent` permissions in your `manifest.json`". WOW! How exhausting. Now on to getting my code to actually work

Answer (score 2):

If you just added `delarativeContent` permission to the manifest.json, remember to remove the extension and add it back again. Permissions might be added during installation only.